# Generate all binary strings from given pattern(wildcard) in python

Tags: python

Given a pattern , we need to generate all possible binary numbers by filling the missing places in the pattern by `0 and 1`.

E.g.

```
Pattern = "x1x";
```

Output :

```
010 
110 
011 
111
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is relatively simple recursion and doesn't require the use of a library:

```
def process(patt):
    if "x" not in patt:
        print(patt)
    else:
        process(patt.replace("x", "0", 1))
        process(patt.replace("x", "1", 1))


process("x1x")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
010
011
110
111
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method using list(queue). It pops the first entry in the list and finds the first occurrence of "x" in the input string and replaces it by "0" and then "1" and then append these 2 new strings to the list. It goes until there is no "x" left in the list. I believe this one is one of the simplest way with a simple `while` loop:

```
def pattern_processor(list):
    while "x" in list[0]:
        item=list.pop(0)
        list.append(item.replace("x", "0", 1))
        list.append(item.replace("x", "1", 1))
    return(list)
```

Driver code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(pattern_processor(["11x1x"]))
```

output:

```
['11010', '11011', '11110', '11111']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
def pattern(str1, idx):
    str = list(str1)
    if idx == len(str):
        print(''.join(str))
        return 0
    if str[idx] == 'x':
        # replace 'x' by '0' and recurse
        str[idx] = '0'
        pattern(str, idx + 1)
        # replace 'x' by '1' and recurse
        str[idx] = '1'
        pattern(str, idx + 1)
        # No need to backtrack as string is passed by value to the function

    else:
        pattern(str, idx + 1)

str = "x1x"
pattern(str, 0)
```

Output :

```
010
011
110
111
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=2)`, and then filter the output to suit your needs:

```
>>> import itertools
>>>
>>> [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(['0', '1'], repeat=3) if x[1] == '1']
['010', '011', '110', '111']
```

Comment: And if the input is "xx1" ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible way to solve it using `itertools`:

```
import itertools

pattern = "x1x"

a = [['0','1'] if (c == 'x') else c for c in pattern]
b = [''.join(lst) for lst in list(itertools.product(*a))]
for s in b:
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
010 
110 
011 
111
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another one making use of the python regular expression module **`re`** and **`itertool`** as seen in other answers already.

```
import re
import itertools

pattern = 'x1x'
patt = re.compile(pattern.replace('x', '.'))

pattern_length = len(pattern)

perms = [ '1','0'] *pattern_length

ls = list()
for x in itertools.permutations(perms, pattern_length):
  ls.append(x)

func = lambda x: ''.join(x)

keep = list()
for x in ls:
  x_ = func(x)
  if patt.match(x_) and not x_ in keep:
    keep.append(x_)

for k in keep:
  print k
```

ouput:

```
110
111
011
010
```